# Preview layer not being constrained to UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints, avfoundation, avcapture

My Swift code below is trying to constrain the previewLayer to the bounds of the UIView which is named camera view. However that is not happening. The previewLayer is much bigger than the constraint cameraView UIView. The cameraView is constrained via storyboard constraints. I just want the 2 objects to be the same position and size.

[image]

[image]

```swift
           import AVFoundation;import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    }


    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front{


                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)




                        }

                        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        _ = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                        let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                        let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")
                        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                        movieOutput.startRecording(to: fileURL, recordingDelegate: self)


                        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                            print("test")
                            self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
                        }



                    }

                }
                catch{

                    print("Error")
                }

            }
            viewDidAppear(animated )
        }

        func viewdidappeare(_ animated: Bool) {
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            self.cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)





        }






    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("FINISHED \(error)")
        // save video to camera roll
        if error == nil {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this as follow:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       self.previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
 }
```

And

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
self.cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)
```

So Your full updated code:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    }


    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front{


                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                            self.cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)


                        }

                        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        _ = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                        let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                        let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")
                        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                        movieOutput.startRecording(to: fileURL, recordingDelegate: self)


                        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                            print("test")
                            self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
                        }



                    }

                }
                catch{

                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("FINISHED \(error)")
        // save video to camera roll
        if error == nil {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not having any affect preview layer is still the same size.

Comment: What this code does is place the uiview in its constraint position over the preview layer. So I can see the uiview. However the preview layer is still taken up the entire screen.

Comment: remove line from your code `self.cameraView = self.view` and check with my code

Comment: Also put screenshot in your question what did you get?

Comment: Added Screenshot and updated code above. On the right track but the preview layer is only taking about 1/4 of the view.

Comment: Black portion is your cameraView Right? and can you post screenshot of constraints set by you for cameraView in storyboard?

Comment: Black portion is cameraView. I just added a photo of the storyboard screen shots.

Comment: storyboard constraints.

Comment: Try to move your `previewLayer` related code from `viewWillAppear()` to `viewDidAppear()` and check

Comment: I updated my code above with what I believe your suggestions. Having not effect not seeing any video at all in the view controller.

Comment: @YaoSmith updated code in your question try to run and check

Comment: Edited my code above. It is not showing any video. I dont think I can viewdidappear and viewwillappear in the same class.

Comment: I can only override one of those.

Comment: @YaoSmith updated answer with full code, try to run that code and when I run that code it gives me perfect result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that sublayers are not automatically resized when their parent changes its size. You need to manually do that, e.g. in `layoutSublayers`:

```
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame
}
```

Comment: I put the code into the scope however I am getting this error.